# Positive real number inequality $\frac{m+p}{n+p}\gt\frac{m}{n}$, where $n\gt m\gt 0$ and $p\gt 0$

Tags: inequality

Let $m$, $n$, and $p$ be real numbers such that $n\gt m\gt 0$ and $p\gt 0$. Prove that

$$\frac{m+p}{n+p}\gt\frac{m}{n}$$

My attempt:

$$\frac{m}{n}+\frac{n+p}{n+p}\gt\frac{m}{n}\implies\frac{m(n+p)+n(n+p)}{n(n+p)}\gt\frac{m}{n}\\\implies\frac{mn+mp+n^2+np}{n(n+p)}\gt\frac{m}{n}\implies\frac{n(m+p)+mp+n^2}{n(n+p)}\gt\frac{m}{n}$$

I can't seem to progress from here. I tried to find a way to force a cancellation with the $n$ in the denominator, but couldn't find a plausible approach. Any help?

Comment: Suggestion:  see what you get when you cross-multiply what you want to prove

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a general relation between $a/b$ and $(a+c)/(b+c)$ where $a,b,c > 0 $?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/734128/is-there-a-general-relation-between-a-b-and-ac-bc-where-a-b-c-0)

Comment: Also related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1989104/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3102218/42969.

Comment: Let $\frac mn=\frac rs=k<1$, since $m<n$. Hence $\frac {m+r}{n+s}=\frac {kn+ks}{n+s}=k$. At follows that $\frac {m+s}{n+s}>k=\frac mn$, i.e. $\frac {m+p}{n+p}>\frac mn$, since $s>r$.

Answer (score 5):

Given your assumptions, write 
$$\frac {m+p}{n+p}-\frac mn=\frac{n(m+p)-m(n+p)}{(n+p)n}=\frac {(n-m)p}{(n+p)n}\gt 0$$

Comment: Is there a way to do it without subtracting both sides by $\frac{m}{n}$?

Comment: You can start from $np \gt mp$, divide by $(n+p)n$ and work with the fractions to get the inequality you want.  It is really the same proof in a different order.

Comment: Ah got it, thanks

Answer (score 4):

Consider $f(x) = \frac{m + x}{n + x}.$ This is an increasing function which can be verified by taking the derivative and seeing that it is everywhere positive. Hence,

$$ f(p) = \frac{m + p}{n + p} > f(0) = \frac{m}{n}.$$

Answer (score 3):

Here is a short proof: as we have positive numbers,
$$\frac{m+p}{n+p}>\frac mn\iff (\not m+p)n>(\not n+p)m\iff pn>pm\iff n>m.$$

This result can be extended to the reverse inequality. Here is a more expressive formulation:

> Let $m,n,p\:$ be positive real numbers.
>
> 1. If $\frac mn <1$, we have $\;\frac mn <\frac{m+p}{n+p}<1$.
> 2. If $\frac mn >1$, we have $\;\frac mn >\frac{m+p}{n+p}>1$.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution.

Let $p=am=bn$ for some real numbers $a,b>0$. Then $$\frac{m+p}{n+p}=\frac{m+am}{n+bn}=\frac{(1+a)m}{(1+b)n}=\frac{1+a}{1+b}\cdot\frac mn$$ so $$\frac{m+p}{n+p}>\frac mn\impliedby\frac{1+a}{1+b}>1\impliedby1+a>1+b\impliedby b<a$$ which is true since $m<n$ and $am=bn\implies\dfrac ba=\dfrac mn<1$. Therefore the original inequality is also true.

Comment: Oh wow, never thought of that. Thx