# Easy way to prove $\frac{2^n+1}{5^n+1}\gt\frac{2^n}{5^n}$ for all $n\gt0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, solution-verification

I've simply said that adding $1$ to the numerator and denominator when the denominator is $5^n$ (greater than $2^n$), the "$+1$" accounts for a larger portion of the numerator than the denominator, so $\frac{2^n+1}{5^n+1}$ better be greater than$\frac{2^n}{5^n}$ for all $n\gt0$.

I'm just not satisfied with this explanation because it seems sloppy and not rigorous... Does someone have a better proof?

Comment: Use the fact that if $bd>0$, then $\frac{a}b>\frac{c}d$ if and only if $ad>bc$: you can convert the first inequality to the second by multiplying both sides by $bd$, since multiplying by a positive number does not change the direction of the inequality.

Comment: What you say is correct and you can prove that $(a+1)/(b+1)>a/b$ is equivalent to $a<b$ (assuming $a, b$ are positive).

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/543682/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/734128/42969

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{2^n+1}{5^n+1} >\frac{2^n}{5^n}$$
$$ \Leftrightarrow (2^n+1)5^n > (5^n+1)2^n$$
$$ \Leftrightarrow 2^n 5^n + 5^n > 2^n 5^n + 2^n $$
$$ \Leftrightarrow 5^n > 2^n $$
which is true for $n>0$

Comment: Similar to Brian's comment, this makes sense, not sure why I didn't think of it sooner

Answer (score 3):

Just show that $LHS - RHS>0$.

$$\frac{2^n+1}{5^n+1}-\frac{2^n}{5^n} = \frac{10^n+5^n-10^n-2^n}{5^n(5^n+1)} = \frac{5^n-2^n}{5^n(5^n+1)} >0$$

(As $5^n>2^n \forall n>0$ and the denominator is always positive.)

Or $\dfrac{2^n+1}{5^n+1} >\dfrac{2^n}{5^n}$

Comment: I completely understand this, the only reason I'm not accepting it is because it seems slightly more complicated than @Blitzer's answer

Comment: No problem, I too agree =)

Comment: That, and I have $0$ experience with logic so I don't even know what the upside-down A looking thing means

Comment: That $\forall$ means "for all"

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that, I guess I could've looked at the MathJax 'code' for the symbol and put two and two together

Answer (score 0):

Think batting averages.  $\frac{2^n+1}{5^n+1}$ is some sort of weighted average of $\frac{2^n}{5^n}$ and $\frac 11 = 1$, so it must be greater than $\frac{2^n}{5^n}$.

Comment: I'm not following this, what if the batting average was $\frac{5^n}{2^n}$? now that would not be greater than $\frac{5^n+1}{2^n+1}$ just because $\frac{1}{1}=1$

Comment: And it's true that $\frac{5^n}{2^n} \gt \frac {5^n+1}{2^n+1}$.  Now you're taking a weighted average of a number greater than $1$ with $1$.  In general, it's pretty easy to prove that if $\frac ab \lt \frac cd$, then $\frac ab \lt \frac{a+c}{b+d} \lt \frac cd$.

Comment: I also meant to say it the other way around and that the “$+1$’s” don’t make $\frac{5^n}{2^n}$ any bigger, but actually makes it smaller

Comment: Again, that's because you're taking a weighted average of $1$ with a number that's greater than $1$.  You'll end up with something in between them.